# How to count 'on event' in CANoe Capl?

Tags: timer, capl, canoe

I'd like to count on event for 200ms.
I tried with this code in CANoe Capl but it's not working well.
I don't know what the problem is. 
help me plz.

MainActivity.Capl

```
variables
{ 
  int timerConditionChecker = 0;
  int lockStatusMonitor = 0;

  mstimer conutCheckTimer;
}

on timer conutCheckTimer
{
  //do nothing
}

on sysvar_update sysvar::Frame2
{
    if(timerConditionChecker == 0)
    {
      lockStatusMonitor++;
      timerConditionChecker = 1;
      setTimer(conutCheckTimer, 500);
    }
    else if(timerConditionChecker == 1)
    {
      if(timeToElapse(conutCheckTimer) > 200)
      {
        timerConditionChecker = 2;
      }
      else
      {
        lockStatusMonitor++;
      }
    }
    else if(timerConditionChecker == 2)
    {
      timerConditionChecker = 3;
      Write("lockStatusMonitorCount = %d",lockStatusMonitor);
    }
    else{}
}
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve and what exactly _is not working well_?

Comment: I'd like to count how many times the on sysvar_update.. I expected 10 count but is was 1.. I want to check my code is wrong or not.

Comment: You want to count how often `on sysvar_update ...` was called within 200ms? Or 500ms? or 300ms? As you can see from your code, the `lockStatusMonitor` is increased only when the sysvar is updated for the first time or if the later updates do not come earlier than 300 ms after the first update. If the second update comes within 300ms after the first update, the count will remain 1. Is that what you want?

Comment: thanks for comment sir. 'on sysvar_update sysvar::Frame2' will update by 20ms, so I will check 10 times updated for 200ms.

Answer (score 1):

What about this (I mostly used your variable names):

```c
variables
{ 
  int lockStatusMonitor = 0;

  mstimer conutCheckTimer;
}

on timer conutCheckTimer
{
  // Is called after 200ms and will output how often the sysvar was updated within these 200ms
  Write("lockStatusMonitorCount = %d",lockStatusMonitor);
}

on sysvar_update sysvar::Frame2
{
    if(isTimerActive(conutCheckTimer))
    {
        // In case the 200ms have already started, just count
        lockStatusMonitor++;
    }
    else {
        // Timer is not yet active, so start counting for the next 200ms now
        lockStatusMonitor = 0; // or = 1 depending on whether your use case
        setTimer(conutCheckTimer, 200);
    }
}
```

Apart from that, using the CAPL debugger should help you to solve these kind of problems.

Comment: @bob, if this answer solves your problem, you should consider to [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).